# How can I zip a file using Cygwin and bzip2?

Tags: cygwin, bzip2

I have downloaded Cygwin and the package to zip files (bzip2) but I cant figure out how to use its command to simply zip a file to another location.

All I want to do is something like:

```
bzip2 myfile somelocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```
bzip2 --keep [file to zip] > [Destination]
```

Omit brackets when filling in the details.

So, for your example, you would want to say:

```
bzip2 --keep myfile > somelocation
```

bzip2 writes to standard output, so you just need to use basic shell tools to direct or pipe this output to your destination. Your destination will be a file, not a folder, so if you want the compressed file to go inside a folder called somelocation, you would want to say something like

```
bzip2 --keep myfile > somelocation/myfile.bz2
```

The --keep parameter tells bzip2 not to delete your original file. If you do want to delete it, omit this parameter.

I tested this with my own installation of Cygwin on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to zip it or convert it to a normal .zip file in the end? I was able to zip it it but the type of the zipped file is .bz2

Comment: If you need a zip file you need to install the zip and the unzip packages. Bzip2 and zip use different compression algorithms